# Hibernate not closing connection

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, rest, jersey

I am using Hibernate + jersey Rest And Mysql as backend for database. In Hibernate used cp3 pool for connection but after some time it creates so many idle connections and gets stuck. my configurations are  :

[image]
[image]

```
package com.appname.hibernate.util;
import org.hibernate.HibernateException;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration;

public class HibernateUtil {
private static SessionFactory sessionFactory;

static {
    try {
        Configuration configuration = new Configuration().configure();

        sessionFactory = configuration.buildSessionFactory();
    } catch (HibernateException he) {
        System.err.println("Error creating Session: " + he);
        he.printStackTrace();
        throw new ExceptionInInitializerError(he);
    }
}

public static SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
    return sessionFactory;
}
}
////////////////////// INSIDE DAO ///////////////////////////

private Session getSession() {

SessionFactory sessionFactory = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory();
Session session;
try {
    session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
} catch (org.hibernate.HibernateException he) {
    session = sessionFactory.openSession();
}
return session;
}

public Users regsiterUser(Users users) throws Exception {

Session session = null;

try {
session = getSession();
Transaction transaction = session.beginTransaction();
session.saveOrUpdate(users);
transaction.commit();
return users;

//Using context session that is why I am not closing session
} catch (Exception e) { throw e; }
}
```

I am calling this DAO function form my controller where I am making transaction and session inside DAO layer. Please help me I am trying to solve this but not getting any solution please have a look what is wrong with the above configuration and code ......

Thanks in advance.....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this `session = sessionFactory.openSession();` should be closed manually after use because it is not managed by an orchestrator that release resource after use.

Comment: As I am using Using context session that is why I am not closing session

Comment: I'm not sure about that, but context defines getCurrentSession() contract and open/close management only on commit/rollback (I can't see rollback here)

Comment: But I am using transaction.commit(); on registration completion.And do you want to say that in this case I have to use commit in all the case of CURD operation ?

Comment: Ok for commit, but what about rollback? Is missing

Comment: I have checked that I never get exception in transaction,  So does it so important to have rollback but still I have used rollback even though I am facing problem..